# No communication between the frontend and the backend after containerizing with docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, mern

I am new to docker. I am trying to use docker for containerizing my MERN stack application.
This is my Dockerfile for the backend

```
#  Dockerfile for Node Express Backend

FROM node

# Create App Directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install Dependencies
COPY ./package.json ./

RUN npm install 

# Copy app source code
COPY . .

# Exports
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

this is my Dockerfile for the frontend

```
# Dockerfile for React client

# Build react client
FROM node

# Working directory be app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json ./

###  Installing dependencies

RUN npm install 

# copy local files to app folder
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: mockup-quora-backend
    container_name: myapp-node-server
    command: npm run start
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    env_file: ./backend/.env
  client:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: mockup-quora-frontend
    container_name: myapp-react-client
    command: npm run start
    depends_on:
      - server
    stdin_open: true    
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

My docker-compose file along with both frontend and backend images were created successfully.

```
PS I:\Mockup-Quora> docker-compose ps  
       Name                     Command               State           Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
myapp-node-server    docker-entrypoint.sh npm r ...   Up      0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp
myapp-react-client   docker-entrypoint.sh npm r ...   Up      0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp
```

Both my containers are up and running but the requests from port 3000 are unable to communicate with port 5000 as there is no connection established between the two ports.

Can anyone help me in fixing this issue??

Comment: Are you proxying the client requests (e.g. proxy in client package.json)?

Comment: How the client connects to server if not using docker?